# Reproducing a shader with pixi.js

Tags: javascript, pixi.js, shadertoy

I'm trying to reproduce this [shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/clfGW8) with **pixi.js**. I am lost because there's no **fragCoord** and no **fragColor** in the code. Moreover I don't understand the declarations in the loop. Here is one of my numerous attempts:

```c
   precision mediump float;
    uniform vec2 iResolution;
    uniform float iTime;


    void main(){
      vec4 O = vec4(0.0);
      vec2 F = gl_FragCoord.xy;
      vec2 r = iResolution.xy;
      float i = .3;
      float l = length(F+=F-r)/r.y + i;
      float t = iTime;

      for(O *= 0.; i < 12.; O += length(min(r.y/abs(F),r)) / 300.0*(cos(++t+i+vec4(0,1,2,0))*l+l)) {
         F *= mat2(cos(l*.2-i++*--t/1e2+vec4(0,33,11,0)));
      }
      gl_FragColor = O;
     }
```

I get an error: `'for' : Invalid init declaration`. How to reproduce this shadertoy with **pixi.js**? Can it be due to the version? (I'm using an old one).

Comment: `ShaderToy` shows you the full shader source code at the bottom of the page if you click on the `Compiled in 0.0s` texts. It's not a full free-standing shader, but rather just implements the "logic" bits and hands it off to ShaderToy to embed in a "full" pixel shader.

Also, the example here is clearly code-golfed, which limits it utility as a learning resource.

`GL_FragColor` is pretty outdated, nowadays people explicitly specify an output (as you can see in the full example). To fix the syntax error in the loop, just keep un-golfing the code (you're pretty much halfway there already).

Comment: @Cubic Hmm ok ; may be i should update pixi then, I'm using a very old version.

Comment: Just to clarify: It's an outdated way to program shaders. It's still available for compatibility purposes, and in this case it's not the cause of the error.